# Best approach to relocate with family while studying in the US

Tags: phd, international-students

I am intending to pursue a PhD program (pharmaceutics) in the US. I will have a student visa. I am trying to figure out the best approach to take so as to move with my family (wife and 2 children who are currently aged 4 years and 10 years respectively).

I will be funded entirely by stipends I may get while studying, so I am wondering:

- Is it possible for student stipends and on-campus/off-campus jobs
  support the entire family expenses (basic things, accommodation and
  school fees for the kids) while pursuing my PhD?
- What are the chances or ways to get my wife a job?
- Which state can I find affordable houses that can accommodate a
  family of four?

Comment: You need to check what a student visa allows you to do in the US (off-campus jobs are not allowed I believe, but I'm not an expert). And you wife would need a visa allowing her to work, which may not be easy to obtain. Public schools are free in the US.

Comment: Your wife will be on F-2 visa. It's not easy for her to get permission to work.

Comment: In general it's hard to immigrate to the US. We've had politicians and political parties who tell people that the reason they don't have a better job is because it was stolen by an immigrant, or that immigrants are violent threats (these are wrong, but politics isn't required to be right). A student visa is easier to get specifically because it is not a direct pathway to permanent immigration.

Comment: "school fees for the kids" primary and secondary education in the US is free, unless you insist on private/religious schooling which would definitely make this whole thing more challenging ... likely the yearly fees are your entire stipend.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way in which graduate students are funded in the US. It ranges from students who pay for everything (food, rent, fees, tuition, office supplies, computers, travel to conferences and health insurance, etc.) to fully-funded positions that cover all of these. Yes, including meals, and I know because I had such a position while a graduate student. Departments offer more to attract better graduate students, so you can expect the better funded positions to be more competitive. Between those two extremes, everything goes. Most graduate students get a tuition remission and earn their rent money by working as Teaching Assistants, that is, teaching courses or labs.

It is entirely possible for a family of 4 to support itself while one of the parents goes to graduate school. I did exactly that. There are too many factors to discuss in a short answer here, but in short trying to find such a spot in a New York City or anywhere in California is  impossible, while entirely possible in the south of the US and in Midwest states. Catholic universities have a tradition of supporting students with families with subsidized housing and other incentives.

Student visas only allow you to work on campus, but finding such jobs will entirely depend on the university. Some universities offer good jobs at at good pay (e.g. museum assistant, library work, research assistant, office work, etc.), while at other universities competition for any kind of on-campus job is fierce and the jobs not nice (e.g. night shift at study hall, event catering, etc.). It's entirely possible to hold more than one job, although, of course, the more jobs you have the less time you'll have to work on your research. But what people don't understand is that for many international students, the alternative is not extra jobs vs. not driving a nice car, but extra jobs vs. not getting a PhD at all. One needs to pay for food and rent, there's no way around that.

As the spouse of a student on a visa, your wife will not get a work permit. But off-the-books jobs in the US are plentiful, and in fact, the entire economy depends on a subclass of people working but receiving no benefits like social security, unemployment benefits, worker's comp, etc. I am a US-born natural citizen but grew up in another nation, so I identify more with immigrants than with my fellow US citizens, and in graduate school mostly socialized with immigrant students. Their spouses held a myriad of jobs, e.g. picking fruit, working in factories, bartending, construction, landscaping, that is, every job US citizens balk at doing because of the harsh conditions and low pay. Which jobs your spouse can get will depend mostly on the color of her skin and accent. If you are Irish or English, she should easily be able to jet a job as a bartender or high-end nanny. If you have brown skin and an accent, then it's construction, fruit picking, meat factory, cleaning, etc.

The trick to making ends meet as an immigrant family of a graduate student is to ask other immigrants. Most US citizens are oblivious to the lives of immigrants, except for what they watch on TV. But immigrants do find a way, and it's not impossible.

Comment: "It is entirely possible for a family of 4 to support itself while one of the parents goes to graduate school. I did exactly that." To clarify, did you do that while your partner did not work?

Comment: `...your wife will not get a work permit. But off-the-books jobs in the US are plentiful...` Bad idea

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- She worked for about 25% of the time while I was a graduate student. Lots of factors went into the decision.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for student stipends and on-campus/off-campus jobs support the entire family expenses (basic things, accommodation and school fees for the kids) while pursuing my PhD?

It's a stretch.

- These stipends are usually sufficient for a single student to find a decent apartment (often shared) and buy meals and other necessities. Stretching this to cover a family of four will be tough.
- Your wife will probably not be allowed to work (legally) in the US.
- It is unlikely that you will be allowed to work off campus. You would have to apply for permission from ICE, and [their guidelines](https://www.ice.gov/sevis/employment) state that such applications will be approved only after you've been here for a year, and only if your economic situation has deteriorated from what it was during that first year, due to factors beyond your control.

> Which state can I find affordable houses that can accommodate a family of four?

You can look up cost-of-living calculators. But bear in mind that schools in less expensive areas usually offer lower stipends, whereas schools in more expensive areas may offer subsidized, on-campus housing. So it's not necessarily as simple as "which state is cheapest."

I recommend reaching out to some of the schools you're interested in and ask if there are any grad students in a similar situation to you that can tell you what worked for them.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is the big cities that are expensive here, especially housing, especially the Bay Area of California. A more rural university (in any state) might have cheaper housing, but possibly not if the university is large. In your field(s) this might be a problem due to the location of suitable universities. You will need to do some research on that.

Your spouse probably won't be able to work for pay, but you might be able to reduce living expenses a bit by sharing some things (child care) with other families.

Schooling for children is free here (public schools). In university towns it can be quite good. Private schools are expensive, sometimes very expensive.

There may still be a few universities that provide low cost married student housing (small 2BR apartments) for graduate students, but this seems to be disappearing, I think.

Grants for graduate study are rare in most fields, especially for international students. Most of the funding is for Teaching Assistants, but only in fields and places that have a large undergraduate major in that field, requiring lots of assistants. There are also Research Assistantships in some fields, but less common. This might be your best bet, given your field. A TA stipend is generally sufficient to live (cheaply) for someone with a family. Can your kids share a room? Harder if not.

Moving from a student visa to a permanent one might be an issue in the long term if that is your desire.

If you have some special qualifications that add value to the department you wish to join, special experience or skills, you might be able to negotiate a bit. But this is also rare, unless you can appeal to some professor (PI) who is well funded and needs your skills.

Good luck.

---

I'm not quite as pessimistic as Bryan Krause, though what he says is true. But academics will be more welcoming of immigrants than politicians. I expect that if you can make it work at all, you won't find many issues at the university or among the university community. Your spouse, for example, might be able to join a circle of student spouses that can be rewarding, though not financially. With shared child care, your spouse might even be able to become a student there.

Comment: I wasn't intending to be pessimistic, just realistic: student visas may be an immigration pathway in other countries, they may have been in the US in the past, but these days they are pretty much orthogonal. The only way they interact with long-term immigration is the local networking that opens up other opportunities (jobs to sponsor a work visa, a citizen to be a spouse - not particularly useful for OP) and the skills learned. There is no simple answer like "complete these forms" or "follow these steps" available.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I understand, and, unfortunately, the places where the politicians seem to be worst are also (some of) the places with lower living expenses, I think.